# Ansible cant parse inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to create a ansible inventory with the command

```
ansible inventory --inventory=./module7_task0/ansible/inventory.yml --list
```

Here is my inventory.yml file

```
all: 
  hosts:
    ec2-3-139-239-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        ec2-3-139-239-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:
    jenkins:
      hosts:
        ec2-3-139-239-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:
    production:
      hosts:
        ec2-3-139-239-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:
```

This is the error that I get when I run the above command

```
WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/vagrant/validation/module7_task0/inventory.yml as an
inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

All the formatting seems correct and I am following the documentation to a T from the ansible site.  The yaml format is correct as well.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should try the command `ansible-inventory`

Answer (score 1):

The inventory file is correct

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory.yml --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    jenkins:
      hosts:
        ec2-3-139-239-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: {}
    production:
      hosts:
        ec2-3-139-239-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: {}
    ungrouped: {}
    webservers:
      hosts:
        ec2-3-139-239-155.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: {}
```

Double-check the path of the file. Review all group_vars and host_vars if any. Test the YAML syntax

```sh
shell> yamllint inventory.yml
inventory.yml
  1:1       warning  missing document start "---"  (document-start)
```

The warning about missing document-start does not cause the problem.